# UIAlertController rounded rect textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm having some problems setting up the textfield for my `UIAlertController`.

I'm using this code to add a rounded `textfield` to the `alertcontroller`:

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
  textField.placeholder = @"placeholder";
  textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
}];
```

However, the result is this:

[image]

How do I remove the *outer border* and *background color*? So it looks like what they have in this tutorial: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/09/05/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8.html.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
for textField in alertController.textFields! {
    if let container = textField.superview, let effectView = container.superview?.subviews.first where effectView is UIVisualEffectView {
       container.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
       effectView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try setting background color of UItextView to [UIColor clearColor]